# Question about the definition of cluster algebras.

Tags: abstract-algebra, quiver, cluster-algebra

I have a question about the definition of a seed of a cluster algebra. It is said that a seed is a pair $(R, u)$, where $R$ is a quiver with $n$ vertices,
$u = \{u_1, \ldots, u_n\}$ is a free generating set of the field $Q(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, see Page 10 of  [the paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CGIQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mi.uni-koeln.de%2Fdmv_2011%2Findex%2Fslides%2Fkellerslides.pdf&ei=uoUqUPu-Ce3ryAHf1YH4Cg&usg=AFQjCNH-Ss_asxUL774XMQT4NL7hA8Y8DQ&sig2=73xjjckkuQ2w_-aqQjMrZQ&cad=rja).

I think here $u_i$ is in terms of $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ and $u_1, \ldots, u_n$ generate $Q(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ freely. Is this true? Thank you very much.

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking... The $u_i$ are elements of $Q(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ so they are automatically «in terms of $x_1$, $\dots$, $x_n$». Since the set $u$  is to be, as you write, a free generating set, in particular it generates. What is it that you want to know if it is true?

Comment: @Mariano, yes. For example, I think $u_1$ can be $x_1x_2+x_3$. Every element of $Q(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ can be written as a sum of some products of $u_1, \ldots, u_n$. Is this true?

Comment: Yes what? :-) I do not understand what you are asking! But no, not every element of $Q(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ can be written as a sum of some products of $u_1$, $\dots$, $u_n$: for example, if $u_i=x_i$ this is clearly not true.

Comment: @Mariano, $x_i$ is a sum of products of $u_i=x_i$ (only one factor and one summand).

Comment: I wrote « **not every element** of $Q(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ can be so written»: this does not mean that **no** element can be written that way: for example $\tfrac1{x_1}$ cannot be written as a sum of products of $x_1$, $\dots$, $x_n$, and it is an element of $Q(x_1,\dots,x_n)$...

Comment: You have not yet make clear what it is you are trying to ask. I suggest you edit your question so that it ends with «What I want to to know is if SOMETHING».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each $u_i$ is a rational function in the $x_i$, with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ - that's what it means to be an element of $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)$.

They set of $u_i$ also freely generates $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)$ as a field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$; another way of saying this is that every element of $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)$ can be written *uniquely* as a rational function in the $u_i$.

Comment: No, to say that the $u_i$ form a transcendence basis of the field over $\mathbb Q$ is weaker than saying that they generate this field.  A transcendence base for a field $F$ might generate a subfield of $F$ over which $F$ is algebraic. (Your second "perhaps the most useful" reformulation is correct.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass Corrected - I usually have $\mathbb{C}$ in place of $\mathbb{Q}$, which is where that came from.